# Lines not pulsed fast enough (?))

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, avr, isp

Should this code pulse the PB3 and PB4 pins (MOSI and MISO of an Arduino Uno) at 2ms interval ?

```
#include <avr/io.h>

int main(void) 
{

//  for (byte i = 0; i < 32; i++)
//    pinMode(i, INPUT);

  DDRB |= (1 << PB4);       
  DDRB |= (1 << PB3);       
//  pinMode(PB4, OUTPUT);
  while (1)
  {
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB4);        
    PORTB &= ~(1 << PB3);        
  //  digitalWrite(PB4, LOW);
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//      __asm__ __volatile__("nop");
//    delayMicroseconds(10000);
    delay(1);
    PORTB |= (1 << PB4);        
    PORTB |= (1 << PB3);        
  //  digitalWrite(PB4, LOW);
//    delayMicroseconds(10000);
    delay(1);

  }
}
```

If used for SPI MOSI can do 1 MHz just fine - so my logic analyzer says. MISO would not behave when used by SPI. MISO works in other non-SPI scenario: I am able to use the Arduino for in-system programming other AVR boards.

But the code above pulses neither MISO nor MOSI, as pointed out by the same logic analyzer in the same setup. Should it?

**update**

There has been some issue with the board. Changed it and all works fine now, regardless of using `int main()` alone or also calling `init()` as per @Majenko 's answer

Comment: Code is looking ok. Are you sure that ports are not shorted by something, or driven from somewhere outside?

Comment: @smajli that was probably it. Feel free to turn the comment into an answer

Answer (score 2):

The code *content* works fine while compiled as an Arduino program - that is, using the proper `setup()` and `loop()` structure:

```
void setup() {
    DDRB |= (1 << PB4);       
    DDRB |= (1 << PB3);       
    while (1) {
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB4);        
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB3);        
        delay(1);
        PORTB |= (1 << PB4);        
        PORTB |= (1 << PB3);        
        delay(1);
    }
}

void loop() {
}
```

However the same code will *not* work when using it in `main()`. This is simply because `delay()` will never work. Normally `main()` calls `init()` which then configures TIMER0 to generate the `millis()` and `micros()` count used for the `delay()` functions.

So either use `setup()` and `loop()` instead of `main()`, or make your program call `init()` before anything else:

```
int main() {

    init();

    DDRB |= (1 << PB4);       
    DDRB |= (1 << PB3);       
    while (1) {
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB4);        
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB3);        
        delay(1);
        PORTB |= (1 << PB4);        
        PORTB |= (1 << PB3);        
        delay(1); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. But, it didn't make a difference. Tried both calling `init()` and switching to `setup()`.  As a sidenote, when I go lower with the delays, into tens / hundreds of microseconds, glithces start showing up on the MISO line. Going for even lower delays causes some (fewer) gltiches to also show up on MOSI .

Comment: Then your board is probably broken, or something, because that code *does* work. I tested it. It worked.

Comment: Yes... something like that. I wonder why the lines are doing fine when used as ISP at 19200 baudrate but not when pulsed at similar rates by hand. I am off to more investigations.